# How to save pandas dataframe with float format changed to percentage with 2 decimal places

Tags: python, pandas, csv, format

According to the documentation (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html), we can specify the floating number format in to_csv method of dataframe.

I try to change the float format to 2 decimal percentage with `float_format=':,.2%'` parameter, which works on python console (like `'{:,.2%}'.format(3.14)`), but to_csv gives "incomplete format" error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the old style formatting:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((5,5)))

df.to_csv('test.out', float_format='%.2f', index=False, header=False)

!type test.out
```

Output:

```
0.10,0.90,0.65,0.78,0.70
0.03,0.45,0.75,0.92,0.94
0.49,0.64,0.47,0.28,0.50
0.48,0.09,0.86,0.33,0.55
0.37,0.85,0.97,0.19,0.68
```

You could multiply your data by 100:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((5,5)))*100

df.to_csv('test.out', float_format='%.0f%%', index=False, header=False)

!type test.out
```

Output:

```
48%,73%,30%,4%,54%
76%,53%,58%,41%,22%
97%,44%,58%,59%,60%
95%,85%,47%,67%,88%
4%,73%,66%,70%,97%
```

Comment: Can this display as percentage? So instead of 0.10, it display as 10%.

Comment: Is it possible not to change the original value? The format for 2 decimal floats works with format string, ideally percentage format can work the same way too.

Comment: @liang I don't think so, what `to_csv` is using is the string modulos operator.  The `format` is a modern method that is not included in `to_csv`.

Comment: By modern you mean python 3.x? Python 2.x seems able to display percent format for float too.

Comment: Well, no. `format` is a separate method on it one that extends the old style formating use '%f'.

Comment: Well, that sounds like what pandas can do at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!